# How to combine 2 different models and call them at once in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have created 2 different models using `tensorflow` and `keras` for image classification. Now I want to merge both the models and use both the models at the same time.

I am trying to send 1 video to each model and convert them to frames at `30 FPS`. Then I want to check, say frame `x` from 1st model and frame `x1` in 2nd model and then keep a simple if else statement like

```
if(frame x ==true && frame x1 == true)
   print y
else
   print z
```

So here I am getting the frames and all the information I need. But my only question is how shall I merge the two models. I want to merge them because I want frame `x` and frame `x1` both at `t` seconds, thus helping me know both the image at take at same time.

Comment: If you are feeding the models one frame at a time, it seems like you could simply feed them the exact same frame so that you know they both are looking at time `t`. Is this the case? Or are you giving both models the raw video? In this case, it seems like you would need a way of identifying which output corresponds to which frame, but this would be specific to the model you are using.

Comment: yes i was using raw videos in both cases, but now just to make my work simple i am using frames only. I know which frames are to be taken at input at tine "t". but i am not able to figure out how to call them at once.. I am just a beginner in this so i am having hard time solving this.

Answer (score 0):

it is explained nicely [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3270). in short you need to define a function for initializing each model in its own unique variable scope that you use for both the pretraining and testing

something like

```
def create_model(session, FLAGS, forward_only, name):
  with tf.variable_scope(name):
      model = seq2seq_model.Seq2SeqModel(
      FLAGS.en_vocab_size, FLAGS.fr_vocab_size, _buckets,
      FLAGS.size, FLAGS.num_layers, FLAGS.max_gradient_norm, FLAGS.batch_size, 
      FLAGS.learning_rate, FLAGS.learning_rate_decay_factor, forward_only=forward_only)
      ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.train_dir)
      if ckpt and tf.gfile.Exists(ckpt.model_checkpoint_path):
        print("Reading model parameters from %s" % ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
        model.saver.restore(session, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
      else:
        print("Created model with fresh parameters.")
        session.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
return model
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both models are in Keras, you can simply load them both at the start of your program with something like

```py
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

taken from the [Keras FAQ "How can I save a Keras model?"](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model).

So then you do

```py
model1 = load_model( 'my_model1.h5' )
model2 = load_model( 'my_model2.h5' )
```

and then you can call `predict` on them separately and use the results.